# Get Appointment ID after sending an Appointment

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I have created and sent a appointment using following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952289/how-do-i-create-and-send-appointments-to-microsoft-outlook-calender)

My code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = null;

app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

appt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)app
    .CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
appt.Subject = "Meeting ";
appt.Body = "Test Appointment body";
appt.Location = "TBD";
appt.Start = Convert.ToDateTime("06/01/2012 05:00:00 PM");
appt.Recipients.Add("sanjay.surendra@mycompany.com");
appt.End = Convert.ToDateTime("06/01/2012 6:00:00 PM");
appt.ReminderSet = true;
appt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15;
appt.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
appt.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
appt.Save();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = appt.ForwardAsVcal();
mailItem.To = "sanjay.surendra@mycompany.com";
mailItem.Send();
```

Now i want the unique appointment ID which i can handle it in my code. Please advice

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [Appointment.EntryID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.entryid.aspx) ?

Comment: "A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store." says the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Appointment.EntryID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.entryid.aspx) is what you are looking for. After an item is Saved or Sent (*persisted*) the `EntryID` property is assigned.

```cs
// ...
appt.Save();
string entryID = appt.EntryID;
// ...
```

#### From MSDN:

> *A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the **EntryID property is not set for an Outlook item until it is saved or sent**. The Entry ID changes when an item is moved into another store...*