# How to get information from .msg file (IPM.Appointment) C#

Tags: c#, outlook, msg

I have some Outlook Appointments saved to my local drive. How can I get the subject and the location where the appointment takes place in C# without creating an Outlook Application object (on my computer Outlook is not installed!) and without spending money on a professional solution?

It would be perfect if the solution made an object of type AppointmentItem for me, like this example (which is not working):

```
string path = "C:\\appointments\\myAppointment.msg"
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem(path);
```

Comment: Maybe this link could help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952289/how-do-i-create-and-send-appointments-to-microsoft-outlook-calender

Comment: This link doesn't help: I'm trying to create an AppointmentItem from an existing .msg file.

Answer (score 0):

try using verbatium before the string path name.
e.g.
    string path = @"";

Maybe these links could help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C

[How do I create and send appointments to Microsoft Outlook calender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952289/how-do-i-create-and-send-appointments-to-microsoft-outlook-calender)

Comment: With or without verbatim, during runtime I get the error "80040154 Class not registered". The first link doesn't help because it isn't about creating AppointmentItems from existing .msg files. The second link doesn't help because this solution doesn't have a method to read the location where the appointment takes place (it was written to read MailItems, not AppointmentItems).